# Dynamic Elixir Ecto Query

Tags: sql, elixir, ecto

I have a list of fields, and I want to take that list and dynamically create an Ecto query from it.

I think I can use `Enum.reduce`, but I'm not sure how to get the pieces to work together.

Each field in the list would use an `ilike` and be cast to a text, something like:

```
def lookup(search_term) do
  fields = [:id, :title, :body]

  query =
    from p in Post,
    where: build_query(fields, search_term)
    select: p

  Repo.all(query)
end

def build_query(fields, search_term) do
  Enum.reduce(fields, fn(field) ->
    fragment("CAST(? AS text) ILIKE ?", field(t, ^field), ^search_term))
  end)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) is built with macros and [`from/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#from/2) does actually expand its whole arguments.

One might define their own macros as [described here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1-defining-custom-functions-using-macros-and-fragment) but in your particular case, it’s enough to [*compose a query*](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-composition).

**To compose a query, one reduces a query object on additional ‘actions’.**

The code below should work

```elixir
  @fields ~w|title body|a

  def lookup(search_term) do
    query = from p in Post # prepare the accumulator
    # and then reduce the query to compose
    query = build_query(query, @fields, search_term)
    # add additional tuning
    query = from p in query, select: p.id

    Repo.all(query)
  end

  def build_query(query, fields, search_term) do
    Enum.reduce(fields, query, fn field, query ->
      from q in query,
      where: fragment("CAST(? AS text) ILIKE ?", field(q, ^field), ^search_term)
    end)
  end
```